# html classes with same name within a parent class

Tags: css

I have a parent class which contains 4 sub-classes, each of which contain 2 more classes.  The problem I have is all sub-classes have the same name! As its a wordpress theme I cant change that html so I simply want to use a custom css sheet to change each one individually.  The content differs for each class, so is there a way using child elements or the like?

```
       <div class="feature-box-main site-aligner">
                <div class="feature-box ">
                    <img src="http://orchardeducation.co.za/wp-content/themes/gravida-pro/images/icon1.png">
                    <div class="feature-title">Page Title 1</div><!-- feature-title -->
                    <div class="feature-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc eget sapien nec eros ultricies eleifend non imperdiet tortor. Duis vulputate dignissim ante. Suspendisse vehicula quam vel pharetra molestie.</div>
                    <a href="#">Read More &gt;</a>
                </div><!-- feature-box -->                                                  
                <div class="feature-box ">
                    <img src="http://orchardeducation.co.za/wp-content/themes/gravida-pro/images/icon2.png">
                    <div class="feature-title">Page Title 2</div><!-- feature-title -->
                    <div class="feature-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc eget sapien nec eros ultricies eleifend non imperdiet tortor. Duis vulputate dignissim ante. Suspendisse vehicula quam vel pharetra molestie.</div>
                    <a href="#">Read More &gt;</a>
                </div><!-- feature-box -->                                                  
                <div class="feature-box ">
                    <img src="http://orchardeducation.co.za/wp-content/themes/gravida-pro/images/icon3.png">
                    <div class="feature-title">Page Title 3</div><!-- feature-title -->
                    <div class="feature-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc eget sapien nec eros ultricies eleifend non imperdiet tortor. Duis vulputate dignissim ante. Suspendisse vehicula quam vel pharetra molestie.</div>
                    <a href="#">Read More &gt;</a>
                </div><!-- feature-box -->                                                  
                <div class="feature-box last">
                    <img src="http://orchardeducation.co.za/wp-content/themes/gravida-pro/images/icon4.png">
                    <div class="feature-title">Page Title 4</div><!-- feature-title -->
                    <div class="feature-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc eget sapien nec eros ultricies eleifend non imperdiet tortor. Duis vulputate dignissim ante. Suspendisse vehicula quam vel pharetra molestie.</div>
                    <a href="#">Read More &gt;</a>
                </div><!-- feature-box --><div class="clear"></div>                                 
        </div>
```

Comment: I want to change the img, title and content of each one, but they all will be different

Comment: CSS cannot change **actual** content..only style it. It's not clear what you are trying to do. Also you might want to delete your original question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30623408/edit-classes-with-same-name-within-a-class-using-only-css

Comment: I simply want to find away of changing the .feature-title content (eg.Page Title 1, Page Title 2 etc etc) to my own headings as well as the .feature-content.  Its a wordpress theme, I can change them with a custom css sheet but then they all change to the same thing! I want to target each class individually and put different content in each one?

Comment: you can find the child element inside the parent div and can update it.

Answer (score 0):

simply use the [n(th) child selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp):
Notice the space between the classes, otherwise you are looking for one element with both classes.

```
.feature-box-main .feature-box:nth-child(1) {
    /*styles for first div here*/
}
.feature-box-main .feature-box:nth-child(2) {
    /*styles for second div here*/
}
```

Also, since you mentioned you want to change the image and title, if you mean not just css changes maybe jQuery come in hand like this:

```
var div1 = $('.feature-box-main .feature-box').eq(1);
var div2 = $('.feature-box-main .feature-box').eq(2);

//for example:
div1.children('.feature-title').html('new Title');
div2.children('img').attr('src','new-imge.jpg');
```

Comment: Thanks guys for the help, will see which works best.

Comment: Please notice the space between the classes

Answer (score 0):

Select the first `div` with:

```
.feature-box-main.feature-box:nth-child(1) {
// styles
}
```

and the second `div` with

```
.feature-box-main.feature-box:nth-child(2) {
// styles
}
```